# Detect unmounted volumes on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to be able to detect when a Volume is being unmounted on Windows (it could be either an external USB/FireWire/eSATA drive, or a Network Shared Folder, or any other kind of Logical Volume).

I found the `RegisterDeviceNotification()` function on MSDN that is popular for detecting USB drives connection/disconnection. Can this function also work with all kinds of Volumes, or just external physical devices?
If not, do you have any idea of what I could use to do that (other than polling)?

Last question, I am new to C++ on Windows, and the `RegisterDeviceNotification()` doc says that my first parameter should be `A handle to the window or service that will receive device events for the devices specified in the NotificationFilter parameter.`

In my case, I would have wanted to register for notifications in my program's `main()` function, and have some kind of `onNotificationReceived()` method to handle the notifications. Can I do this (and if yes, how), or do I have to register another window/service that runs in another process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WM_DEVICECHANGE` notifies applications of volume arrival and removal, and you don't even have to call `RegisterDeviceNotification()`.

Look for `dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME`.

There's [an example in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215.aspx).

Comment: This sounds like what I want to do, so, in order to receive those messages, I just need to declare a callback function in my program? Where can I find the signature of this function? Thanks!

Comment: @nbarraille: `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages should be sent to all top-level windows.  So handle them in your WndProc, or whatever place your favorite framework gives you for handling window messages.

Comment: My program is just a console program, it has no Window. How can I register it to receive those notifications?

Comment: Make a hidden window (console programs can create windows).  And a message loop.  It might make sense to do both in a separate thread, so it doesn't interfere with your control flow as much.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the unique volume name for an unmounted drive  :  http://help.lockergnome.com/windows2/unique-volume-unmounted-drive--ftopict477553.html

`FSCTL_IS_VOLUME_MOUNTED` Determines whether the specified volume is mounted, or if the specified file or directory is on a mounted volume  :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364574(v=vs.85).aspx

How to detect if there is a volume mounted on that drive letter.

```
bool DiskInDrive(
  std::wstring const& inDrive)
{
  std::wstring volume = std::wstring(L"\\\\.\\") + inDrive.substr(0, 2);

  HANDLE h = CreateFileW(
    volume.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL);

  if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    // 2 means "no disk", anything else means by inference "disk
    // in drive, but you do not have admin privs to do a
    // CreateFile on that volume".
    return lastError != 2;
  }

  DWORD bytesReturned; // ignored
  BOOL devSuccess = DeviceIoControl(h, FSCTL_IS_VOLUME_MOUNTED, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &bytesReturned, NULL);

  if(devSuccess == FALSE)
  {
    DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
    (void)lastError; // For debugging.
    // Presumably, any error means "no disk in drive", or more
    // accurately, "no volume mounted on that drive letter".
    CloseHandle(h);
    return false;
  }

  CloseHandle(h);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but you might want to look into creating a Windows Shell Extension which can receive notifications for various changes to the system.

For example, implementing the `IShellChangeNotify` interface includes an `OnChange` method which can receive a whole range of notifications including `SHCNE_DRIVEREMOVED, SHCNE_MEDIAREMOVED, SHCNE_NETUNSHARE` and so on.

You would have to create and register a DLL (i.e it wouldn't be a standalone exe), but I think  it would provide you with the kinds of notifications you're looking for.